# How to solve for voltage using node voltage method?

Tags: capacitor, voltage

How would you solve for \$V_x\$ using node voltage method. I can solve this using \$Q_{initial}=Q_{final}\$, but I can't solve it using node voltage.

Using node voltage I get \$v(t)-v(0)=\frac{k}{170\mbox{ aF}}\$. I'm not sure how to solve for the k constant or if this is even correct.

[image: Homework Problem Image]

Comment: Just to clarify, the voltage generators are DC and you need voltage once the circuit stabilizes, right? If that's the case, I might be able to post procedure how to get the calculation using node voltage method in a couple of hours.

Comment: If these are ideal voltage sources and capacitors, isn't this a paradoxical circuit?  Like connecting an ideal voltage source to an ideal short.

Comment: 10 aF is more or less the capacitance between two 1 m2 plates placed 1000 km apart. I don't have them in my component box.

Comment: @endolith, there will be a tau of 0. It will immediately reach "steady state". The pre-charged and then leave a floating node makes me laugh.

Comment: @stevenvh  Well your plates are huge.  It could also be 113 µm² plates 1 mm apart.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your instructor considers the "node voltage method", but this is easy to solve.

First note that turning on each voltage source results in some positive step on Vx, and that each positive step can be computed independently and then summed to get the net step on Vx when the supplies are turned on.

Next note that for the purpose of analysing the result of a single supply stepping on, the other three capacitors are in parallel connected to ground since all the supplies have 0 impedance (by definition of a voltage source).  So for each supply, the step on Vx is the result of a capacitive voltage divider between the capacitor in series with that supply and the parallel combination of the other capacitors.  The absolute value of the capacitors don't matter, just their ratios.

The 5V step is divided by 50aF and 120aF.  5V * 50 / 170 = 1.471V.

Left 1V step: 1V * 10 / 170 = 59mv

Bottom 1V step: 1V * 100 / 170 = 588mV

2V step: 2V * 10 / 170 = 118mV

Adding up all the contributions yields a step of 2.235V.  Adding this to the initial state of 2V yields the final answer of 4.235V.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is node voltage method.

But you can replace the capacitors with a voltage source \$V_c\$.

With this you can use the differential equation: \${dV_c\over dt} = i_C \cdot {1\over C}\$

The current \$i_C\$ is calculated by shorting all voltage sources one by one, and calculate the currents \$i_C\$.

You will end up with four first-order differential equations, which then easily can be solved.